# (C++ multithread / socket) When two clients connect with server, first connection disconnected

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I'm making simple chatting program with c++.

The structure of the server program like this,

■ MAIN

- check client connection
- if client connected -> make sub thread to connection with client

■ SUB THREAD

- recv message from client
- when client disconnected, delete User(custom class) Object from userList(std::vector)

The problem is, when I execute one client, sending message to server works well.
And execute second client(it means two clients have connection with server at the same time), second client send message is fine, but when send message to server with first client, first client disconnected from server.

I tried:

- When I add dump User Object to userList(0), it works well. (why?) => I think something wrong with initialize vector, but i'm not sure.
- I did't use mutex yet, but I think this problem is not cause by not using mutex.

this is my codes:

## Server.cpp

```
#include "Server.h"

void communicateClient(std::vector<User*>* userList, User* user) {
    bool clientConnected = true;
    char recvMessage[Constants::NETWORK_MESSAGE_SIZE] = { 0, };

    while (clientConnected) {
        if (recv(user->getUserSocket(), recvMessage, sizeof(recvMessage), 0) == -1) {
            std::cout
                << Constants::LOG_NETWORK
                << std::to_string(user->getUserSockAddrIn().sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1) << "."
                << std::to_string(user->getUserSockAddrIn().sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2) << "."
                << std::to_string(user->getUserSockAddrIn().sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3) << "."
                << std::to_string(user->getUserSockAddrIn().sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4) << ":"
                << std::to_string(user->getUserSockAddrIn().sin_port) << " client disconnected" << std::endl;
            clientConnected = false;
        }
        else {
            std::cout
                << Constants::LOG_NETWORK
                << std::to_string(user->getUserSockAddrIn().sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1) << "."
                << std::to_string(user->getUserSockAddrIn().sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2) << "."
                << std::to_string(user->getUserSockAddrIn().sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3) << "."
                << std::to_string(user->getUserSockAddrIn().sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4) << ":"
                << std::to_string(user->getUserSockAddrIn().sin_port) << " send message: "
                << recvMessage << std::endl;
        }
    }

    closesocket(user->getUserSocket());

    std::vector<User*>::iterator userIterator;
    for (userIterator = userList->begin(); userIterator != userList->end(); userIterator++) {
        if ((*userIterator)->getUserId() == user->getUserId()) {
            delete(*userIterator);
            userList->erase(userIterator);
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "client count: " << userList->size() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET serverSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN serverAddr;

    std::cout << Constants::LOG_START << "Chatting server started" << std::endl;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << Constants::LOG_ERROR << "Error WSAStartup()" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, Constants::PROTOCOL);
    if (serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << Constants::LOG_ERROR << "Error socket()" << std::endl;
    }
    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, Constants::SERVER_IP.c_str(), &serverAddr.sin_addr);
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(Constants::SERVER_PORT);
    if (bind(serverSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << Constants::LOG_ERROR << "Error bind()" << std::endl;
    }
    if (listen(serverSocket, Constants::CLIENT_CONNECT_LIMIT) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << Constants::LOG_ERROR << "Error listen()" << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<User*> userList;
    std::vector<std::thread*> clientConnectionThread;

    serverState = true;
    while (serverState) {
        std::cout << Constants::LOG_WAIT << "waiting client connection..." << std::endl;

        SOCKADDR_IN clientSockAddrIn;
        SOCKET clientSocket;
        int clientSockAddrInSize = sizeof(clientSockAddrIn);

        clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientSockAddrIn, &clientSockAddrInSize);
        if (clientSocket == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cout << Constants::LOG_ERROR << "Error accept()" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout
                << Constants::LOG_SUCCESS
                << std::to_string(clientSockAddrIn.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1) << "."
                << std::to_string(clientSockAddrIn.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2) << "."
                << std::to_string(clientSockAddrIn.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3) << "."
                << std::to_string(clientSockAddrIn.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4) << ":"
                << std::to_string(clientSockAddrIn.sin_port) << " client connected" << std::endl;
            User* user = new User;
            user->setUserSocket(clientSocket);
            user->setUserSockAddrIn(clientSockAddrIn);
            userList.push_back(user);
            clientConnectionThread.push_back(new std::thread(communicateClient, &userList, std::ref(userList.back())));
            std::cout << "client count: " << userList.size() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::thread>::iterator threadIterator;
    for (threadIterator = clientConnectionThread.begin(); threadIterator != clientConnectionThread.end(); threadIterator++) {
        (*threadIterator).join();
    }

    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

## Client.cpp

```
#include "Client.h"    

int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET serverSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN serverAddr;

    std::cout << "client start" << std::endl;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Failed WSAStartup()" << std::endl;
    }

    serverSocket = socket(PROTOCOL_TYPE, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << "Failed socket()" << std::endl;
    }

    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = PROTOCOL_TYPE;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER_IP.c_str(), &serverAddr.sin_addr);
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    std::cout << "connecting to server..." << std::endl;
    while (true) {
        if (connect(serverSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "Fail to connect server: retry in 2 seconds..." << std::endl;
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    std::string sendMessage;
    char recvMessage[256] = { 0, };

    printf("send message to server...\n");

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Write Message: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, sendMessage);
        send(serverSocket, sendMessage.c_str(), sendMessage.length() + 1, 0);
    }

    closesocket(serverSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you don't store the return value of `recv` in the server. So there is no way for you to output `recvMessage` correctly because your code does not know how many bytes it is. Also, TCP is not a message protocol -- you should *not* call a variable `recvMessage` if it doesn't not contain a message, and it doesn't because TCP is not a message protocol and `recv` has no idea what messages are or how to figure out where they end.

Comment: Also, you have a race condition in your code. You have two threads that both access `userList` with no synchronization whatsoever. If one of the client threads thread is iterating `userList` while the listen/accept thread modifies it -- boom.

Comment: Lastly, we can't see how `getUserId` works and there's a good chance that's where your issue is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I didn't change anything from that code, but when I tried after you answered, it worked well.. haha 
+ getUserId() is not implemented yet.

And you said "two threads that both access userList" comment means use mutex, is that right?

Comment: Your code will fail exactly as you describe if `getUserId` isn't implemented. The code relies on it working to decide what to delete! `if ((*userIterator)->getUserId() == user->getUserId()) {`. Also, fix the other two issues I mentioned in my first two comments -- they'll bite you eventually if they aren't already.